# Dynamically update an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

**QUESTION**:
I have an AsyncTask with a public ArrayList and I wanna know if I can dynamically update this ArrayList without stop the Task.

The thing is that my task load information about the elements in his internal array, at the same time my activity can load more elements so I would like to know if I can push theses new elements into the task's array instead of creating a new task.

**SOLUTION**:

*MY TASK*:

```
public class TaskGetMatchesDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, MatchDetails, Void> {

private FragmentHistory fragmentHistory;

//Dynamic Data, Array where we have to add and remove elements.
private ArrayList<Match> matchesArrayList;

//Constructor
public TaskGetMatchesDetails(FragmentHistory f) {
    this.fragmentHistory = f;
    this.matchesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
}

//SYNCHRONIZED METHODS

public synchronized void addMatch(Match match) {
    if (this.matchesArrayList != null) {
        this.matchesArrayList.add(match);
        Log.d("TASK DETAILS", "ADDED MATCH: " + match.getMatchId());
    }
}

public synchronized Match getFirsMatchFromArrayList() {
    if (matchesArrayList.size() > 0) {
        return matchesArrayList.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}

public synchronized void removeMatchFromArrayList(Match match) {
    if (this.matchesArrayList != null) {
        this.matchesArrayList.remove(match);
        Log.d("TASK DETAILS", "REMOVED MATCH: " + match.getMatchId());
    }
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Match match;
    MatchDetails matchDetails;
    while (!isCancelled()) {

        //If we have not work to do continue
        if (matchesArrayList.size() <= 0) {
            continue;
        }

        //Get the work for this iteration
        Match m = getFirsMatchFromArrayList();

        //If we have already calculated this data we just jump to other cycle
        if (fragmentHistory.getMatchDetails(m.getMatchId()) != null) {
            removeMatchFromArrayList(m);
            continue;
        }

        matchDetails = new MatchDetails();

        //TODO: Here we have to proccess the data.

        publishProgress(matchDetails);
        removeMatchFromArrayList(m);

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    fragmentHistory.setTaskGetMatchesDetails(null);
    cancel(true);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(MatchDetails... matches) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(matches);
    //We save the data calculated in this fragment
    fragmentHistory.addMatchDetails(matches[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

*CREATE THE TASK IN THE FRAGMENT onCreate method*:

```
taskGetMatchesDetails = new TaskGetMatchesDetails(this);
taskGetMatchesDetails.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

*TO ADD A NEW ELEMENT*:

```
taskGetMatchesDetails.addMatch(m);
```

*TO CLOSE THE TASK YOU JUST HAVE TO*:

```
taskGetMatchesDetails.cancel(true);
```

Comment: please explain more what you want and please show your code

Comment: Can't you wait for the task to complete, then check if the arraylist has been updated? If no, perfect, if yes, relaunch the task? I don't think you can update the data used on the background thread, and I don't think that would be a good idea.

Comment: Lets see, I have a task that loads information about elements in his array and my main class can load more elements at the same time so the thing is to add this new elements to the task array so it can continue loading information

Answer (score 1):

The answers are No and Very Carefully.  No-  you can't do this with a list without additional work.  You'd need to either protect access to the data with a semaphore or used a synchronized list.  Otherwise you could concurrently access the list leading to incorrect partial state.  This is bad, especially if both are updating the list at once, that can lead to memory access errors and even crashes.

If you use a synchronized list or semaphore, you can access it but you need to write your algorithm carefully to avoid problems if items are removed/added in midstream.  But answering how to do that is awfully broad, you'd need to give us a more concrete algorithm to do so.

Comment: Thank u bro, I will try to write some code with that idea and share it earlier possible ;)